# Android Grid View: Stack image on top of another

Tags: android, image, gridview

Got a grid view, where each grid item comprises of 2 images and 1 text view.

The main image 'subjectIcon' always displays and in the example below is a red square with a stethescope. The second image, 'favouriteStatus' is a small star image that should display in the top right corner. The text sits underneath the 'subjectIcon' image.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/subjectIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/imagescenario" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/favouriteStatus"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/star_fill_drop" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/subjectTitle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="Subject Title"/>
```

The design view shows this, which is what I want:

[image: Design view]

However, when I run the app, the star image is never shown. Interestingly if I have the text over the top of the main image, that sits on top and shows.

Been hitting my head against a wall now for 3 hours, what am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Grid view xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SubjectListActivity">

<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"

/>


  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, I couldn't see how you relate the three widgets within the `RelativeLayout` .. I mean no relative layout attributes you added to define the location of each widget .. also where do you use the `gridView` ?

Comment: Sorry Zain I have no idea what you're asking? The xml is of one grid item. The design view displays exactly how each grid item should display, but in the app the 2nd image (star) never displays

Answer (score 0):

I have added Layout attributes of the `RelativeLayout` ViewGroup.

They will add constraints to the underlying widgets in order to fit withing the parent, and with respect to one another.

For instance, the `ImageView` that doesn't appear (`favouriteStatus`), added top and right/end constraints to the parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/subjectIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/imagescenario" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/favouriteStatus"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/star_fill_drop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subjectTitle"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Subject Title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Zain, thanks for the answer. I copy and pasted your code but I still have the same issue, where the star image doesn't show. Honestly can't explain it

Comment: Could you please post the `gridview` layout

Comment: This is strange, I tested it now, and didn't manage to reproduce this issue ..

Comment: Thanks for trying, it's not just me at least!

Comment: Upon my test, your layouts looks good (including changes in the answer). So, try to play with images a bit, use other drawables with different sizes and see .. also check if you change something programmatically that might affect on UI, and also review the adapter

Comment: Hi Zain, please see my answer. Any insight into why visibility didn’t work?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, many thanks to Zain for help above. Knowing it wasn't an issue with my XML made me look and alter another area where I found the issue, albeit I'm unsure why this is an issue.

In my code I had a simple IF/ELSE statement where if 'favStatus' was 1 then to show the star image, if 0 then do not.

Initially I had this code:

```
        if (favStatus.equals("1")) {favIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
        else {favIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
```

I found simple changing it to this worked:

```
        if (favStatus.equals("1")) {favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_fill_drop);}
        else {favIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
```

I don't understand why VISIBLE did not work, and I had to set the image filename again (already done in XML) for it to show.

Anyway I have a solution. albeit one I'm not sure why, any enlightenment on this would be appreciated.

Comment: strange and Interesting! can you just set the icon as `invisible` in xml, and remove your shared condition for a while, then `favIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and see

Comment: Tried that and didn't show. Only shows if I set the image path in the activity code and not XML.